# IronPython call to SSRS - how to handle mutable arrays

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ironpython

I'm attempting to translate the following C# code into IronPython but I don't know how to handle the strongly typed mutable arrays.  The code is test code to write a Server Side SSRS report to a local PDF, and runs fine in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace ConsoleBooking
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServerReport report = new ServerReport();
            report.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.1.29/ReportServer");
            report.ReportPath = "/Report Project Media Bookings/Business";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string filenameExtension;

            byte[] bytes = report.Render(
                "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                 out streamids, out warnings);

            string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "business.pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I set the arrays up as

```
streamids = Array.CreateInstance(String, 1)
```

so my call looks like this

```
bytes = report.Render("PDF", None, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension, streamids, warnings)
```

Then I get this rather enigmatic unhandled exception returned

> expected StrongBox[str], got str

How should I code this?

The above report doesn't take any parameters, but in C# these are added using

```
        List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("pBookingID", "6761", false));
        report.SetParameters(paramList);
```

Which again works fine for me in a related report - how do I add this in IronPython?

UPDATE: using bytes, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension, streamids, warnings = report.Render("PDF", null) as suggested by Jeff Hardy gets over the immediate call, but it still crashes with a 'too many values to unpack' error.  Arbitrarily extending the size of the arrays or adding extra parameters does not change this error - and it's difficult to see what's going wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, see [the documentation on *ref* and *out* parameters](http://www.ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#ref-and-out-parameters). Basically, out parameters become part of a returned tuple. This would look something like (untested):

```
bytes, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension, streamids, warnings = report.Render("PDF", null)
```

For the second, try:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

params = [ReportParameter("pBookingID", "6761", False), ...]
report.SetParam(List[ReportParameter](params))
```

Comment: Thanks, so what would the first part look like in code? (just the variable initialization and call)

Comment: I added an example, but haven't tested it.